# Array of numbers Excel 2013

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, numbers

I need to use formula that will create array of numbers in 1 column and 20 rows. Numbers are between 36.1 and 36.8

I'm currently using

=RANDARRAY(20, 1, 36.1, 36.8)

It works fine in my Excel 2021, but I need it for other PC that has Excel 2013 installed.

Comment: `=36.1+RAND()*0.7`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a formula you can use in Excel 2013 to generate a random number between 36.1 and 36.8:

```
=36.1 + (36.8-36.1)*RAND()
```

To create an array of numbers in 1 column and 20 rows:

1. Select the first cell where you want the random number to appear (e.g., A1).
2. Enter the formula `=36.1 + (36.8-36.1)*RAND()` into that cell.
3. Drag the fill handle down to fill 20 rows with the formula.

This will generate 20 random numbers between 36.1 and 36.8 in the selected column.